# porting c++98 applications to c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What breaking changes are introduced in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11)

Is it safe to simply recompile c++98 applications / libraries in c++11 mode? Are there any hidden issues that may cause a program (that compiles cleanly in c++11 mode) to malfunction?

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not "porting".

Comment: Well, lazy-porting. Presumably the standard library could be more efficient in c++11 mode if it can take advantage of move semantics, etc

Comment: For the most part, recompiling everything should work fine. [There are some breaking changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11), however, so you should consider carefully whether those will break your code.

Comment: It depends on the compiler also. You don't compile your code by the specification itself.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes ah, thanks. I didn't find that SO question. In this question I'm looking for specifically stuff that "silently" breaks a program. A failed compile is OK, a successful (mis)compile is very bad... Unfortunately contrary to my first guess, there _are_ silent breaking changes :(