# is it possible to link a library compiled with c++11 to a code which needs to be compiled with c++03

Tags: c++11, compilation, c++03, ogre, bulletphysics

I have ogre rendering code which compiles with c++03 but not with c++11.

I have bullet physics code which compiles with c++11 but not with c++03.

Now I want to interface them. Is it possible to compile bullet code with c++11 and call the resulting library from ogre code that is to be compiled with c++03.

my gcc version 4.8.4

OGRE is built as static. Bullet is also build as static.

Comment: Will the Bullet library be built as a static or shared library? If it's a shared library then then it should work mostly fine, unless you want to call some function or use some class that depends on specific C++11 functionality. If it's a static library then it will not be possible unless you link with a standard library that have the C++11 functionality needed by the library.

Comment: please see edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible as long as you use the same libstdc++ ABI, and as the new C++ 11 ABI has been introduced with g++ 5.1 (see [using dual abi](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html)), it should be ok for you.

edit : see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190269/g-always-backward-compatible-with-older-static-libraries) for a more complete answer, specially regarding ABI incompatibility with g++ 4.7.0 and g++ 4.7.1