# Using library with different compiler flag

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

can we use a library built with a different flag say -std=c++17 with my program which is going to be built using -std=c++11 in these cases.

```
A) Same compiler used to build the library:
case 1: shared lib (.so)
case 2: static library (.a)

B) Different compiler:
case 1: shared lib (.so)
case 2: static library (.a)
```

Comment: Depends on the compiler. Some compilers maintain ABI compatibility (what you'd need) between some standards versions. You'd need to consult the docs for your particular compiler

Comment: What particular thing I should look in compiler docs. I mean the keywords to search for.

Comment: Starting point (may be out of date) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190269/g-always-backward-compatible-with-older-static-libraries