# Passing incorrect type input for a defined variable

Tags: c++, input, g++4.8

According to "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ (2nd Edition)" by Stroustrup, the following program should output the value of -1 for the object 'age'.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int age = -1;
  cin >> age;

  cout << "\nAge:" << age;
}
```

---

```
INPUT: Carlos // string
OUTPUT: 0 // Why not -1 as Stroustrup states ?
```

---

```
C++ Standard: C++ 4.8.1
```

Comment: In C++11, it should be 0. Prior to that (which I assume is the period the book is from), it will be left alone. C++ 4.8.1 is not a thing. You probably mean the GCC version.

Comment: @chris Interesting because the book explicitly states the use of C++11 and some new features from C++14. The book was released this year.

Comment: @user3786689, Then it looks like a remnant from the first edition that was not thought to be changed, or some other oversight. Check the book's errata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than hunt out the C++ standard references, I’ll just quote from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> #### Until C++11
>
> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.
>
> #### Since C++11
>
> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min() is written and failbit flag is set.

So presumably, your book is assuming pre c++11 semantics, but your compiler is using post c++11 semantics.

Comment: Thanks, I guess Stroustrup forgot to fix his own book and still contains pages from the 1st edition.

Comment: Good to know about this change. Sometimes I use the pattern of `int x = failure_value; an_istream >> x;`

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: So I'm nowhere near 100% on this. I'm looking at C++ 2003. 27.6.1.2.2 says that the formatted extractors will use the locale's `num_get<>`, which can be found in 22.2.2.1. If we drop down a bit to 22.2.2.1.2, we see: _If an error occurs, val is unchanged; otherwise it is set to the resulting value._

Comment: FWIW, regardless what is correct in what standard, I would prefer the variable to be left alone and the failbit to be set. Who got the idea to modify the variable when the input can not be converted?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, Probably someone who desired all of the stupid `int x; std::cin >> x; doSomething(x);` code to not trigger UB. Really, though. It does destroy that initial default idiom if it's really guaranteed to work.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522504/istream-behavior-change-in-c-upon-failure and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11/19523324#19523324

Comment: @sharth: just read my first comment again as an answer to your response to that comment. scanf is just UB, which is the reason why this was changed in C++11. from fscanf in C99: "if the result of the conversion cannot be represented
in the object, the behavior is undefined".

Comment: @chris: People will also do `ìnt x; ... some lines of code not involving x ... doSomething(x);`, so that doesn't look very useful to me.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: As far as I can tell, in C++ 2003, it wasn't defined in terms of `fscanf()`. Is that from an earlier standard?

Comment: u can search for "the rules of scanf"

Comment: @sharth: Thanks for the links, but I still don't think it is any better than simply leaving the value unmodified, despite what others say about it.

Comment: The section of the standard you are searching for is [facet.num.get.virtuals] paragraph 3 stage 3 "[...]One of: --zero, if the conversion function fails to convert the entire field. ios_base::failbit is assigned to err."  This was changed in C++11 as part of library issue 23 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#23

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge age is integer and if we assign it chars or string it will no accept and then it will be assigned 0 which is the default for integer.

Comment: Default for integer could mean several things in different situations. I would think the most suitable situation to extrapolate on for "default" would be its value when default-initialized, which is nothing in particular.

Answer (score -2):

addendum: the currently selected "solution" is dangerously incorrect, telling readers to rely on behavior that is really UB, and anonymous downvoters are flocking like gnats to this answer. this is SO. establishing the distance to the moon by anonymous voting.

---

iostreams do not guarantee that a variable used for input will be unchanged when an error occurs.

re

> **”** Why not -1 as Stroustrup states ?

does he really?

since you don’t provide a quote it’s difficult to say anything definitive about that, but I rather doubt that Stroustrup has made that claim.