# Why does a string become an integer in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    int N;
    cout << " Input an integer:";
    cin >> N;
    cout << " The integer entered is:" << N << endl;        
}
```

when I input an Integer it returns the same value but when I input `hello` it gives me `1961729588`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The string doesn't *become* an integer, the `std::cin` operation fails and what you get as output is the garbage value that was in `N` originally. Initialize `N` to 0, and type in "hello" you should see 0 as output.

Comment: Or, just to make the behavior clearer, initialize `N` to `42`, or to `123456`.

Comment: My experiments prove against your theory. Looks like the up to date compilers just reset the variable to it's default constructed value.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Nope, its a change in C++11 [see my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522504/istream-behavior-change-in-c-upon-failure) about this.

Answer (score 5):

> *"when I input an Integer it returns the same value but when I input `hello` it gives me `1961729588?`."*

The `cin >> N;` actually fails returning `false` for the stream state, when a input is given that cannot be converted to an integer. You can check for such error condition with

```
 if(!(cin >> N)) {
     cerr << "Input a valid number!" << endl;
 }
 else {
     cout << " The integer entered is:" << N << endl;
 }
```

The value of `N` will be initialized (reset) to `int()` (default value) which actually renders to `0`.

---

[**Full live sample**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9799a0ad8601e6f1)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    int N;
    cout << " Input an integer:";
    if(!(cin >> N)) {
        cout << "Input a valid number!" << endl;
        cout << "N = " << N << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << " The integer entered is:" << N << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input

```
Hello
```

Output

```
Input an integer:Input a valid number!
N = 0
```

This was cross checked with a [Ideone code sample](http://ideone.com/nRzrUW)

**I cannot reproduce** getting some *garbage value* like `1961729588`. The value was correctly reset by the `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, int&);` input operator.

---

Is it an issue of your current compiler's implementation, c++ standards level (`-std=c++11`) settings?

I have found some notes about eventual differences regarding c++ standards at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get):

[image]

[image]

<sub>Though I didn't spot what they really refer to with *'a value as described above'*, to be honest.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

When you input a non-integer the input fails. When the input fails, `N` retains its original value which isn't defined, i.e., writing results in undefined behavior. You should test your inputs, e.g.:

```
if (std::cin >> N) {
    // do something with the successful input
}
else {
    // deal with the input failure
}
```

Comment: _"N retains its original value"_ I also thought so, but have observed some different behavior. It seems to set to just `T()`, when input fails (checked on Ideone and coliru).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: actually, you may be right: this could be a C++11 change. Traditionally, the value was not changed but to reflect the reason of an error could cause it to be set to some specific value. It seems, the original question wouldn't use a C++11 implementation in this case.

Comment: _"this could be a C++11 change"_ Yeah, looks like. Still I'm admiring you, as the absolute c++ stream expert ;-) ...

Answer (score 1):

When you enter `cin >> N;` the compiler sees that `N` was declared as an `int`. Thus your program will call a function that will attempt to read text representing an `int` from `cin` and store the result in `N`.

To do this it will read as much numeric characters from cin as it can, and stop when a non-numeric character is encountered.

For example if you enter `32\n` your program reads `3`, then `2`, then `\n`. When it sees the `\n` it stops reading, because `\n` is not a number. The program will push `\n` back on to the stream (in case we want to read it later) and store 32 in `N`.

Suppose instead of a number you type some word such as `"hello"`. The your program will read `h` and then stop, because `h` is not a number. `h` will be pushed back onto the stream (to be read later) and nothing will be stored in `N`. `cin` will return an error since no numeric characters were read.

This still does not explain the value of 1961729588.

Notice `N` was never initialised. According to the C++ Standard the value of an uninitialised automatic variable is undefined. Thus the value of `N` will be some garbage value. In your case this was 1961729588.