# cin >> val sometimes reads 0 depending on Ctrl-Z

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, iostream

I was trying to write a code in C++ in Windows using MinGW compiler, my code counts and prints the number of **consecutive** times a number occurs in a given set of input. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int c_val = 0,val = 0,cnt = 1;
    std::cin>>c_val;
    while(std::cin>>val){
        if(val==c_val)
            cnt++;
        else{
            std::cout<<c_val<<" occurs "<<cnt<< " times"<<std::endl;
            c_val = val;
            cnt = 1;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<val<<" occurs "<<cnt<<" times";
}
```

INPUT: `42 42 42 12 13 13 ^Z` (press Enter)

OUTPUT:

```
42 occurs 3 times
12 occurs 1 times
0 occurs 2 times
```

But if I press Enter before `^Z` then it looks like:

INPUT: `42 42 42 12 13 13` (press Enter) `^Z` (press Enter)

OUTPUT:

```
42 occurs 3 times
12 occurs 1 times
13 occurs 2 times
```

I want to know why the variable `val` in my code stores `13`, when I use `^Z` key after pressing my return key and why does it store `0` if I give the `^Z` key along with my input.

Comment: ^Z is not end-of-line character.

Comment: In windows it is, it is entered by pressing Ctrl + z on keyboard

Comment: @dstnyknstrktr End-of-file, not end-of-line.

Comment: the Enter key produces the end-of-line character,  usually called "newline"

Comment: Did you mean to print `c_val`, not `val`, in the last line?

Comment: No I meant val itself, I know that using c_val fixes my problem but my question is not regarding the problem it is about the behavior of my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what happens. I observed this using MinGW-w64 4.9.2.  The behaviour was the same whether running the executable in a Windows console, or under Cygwin  (but not using cygwin-mingw).

- Pressing `^Z` at the beginning of a line sets the end-of-file condition
- Pressing `^Z` anywhere else actually sends ASCII 26 character to the stream

I also observed:

- `cin >> val` sets `val` to `0` if it fails due to the input not containing a number.
- `cin >> val` leaves `val` unchanged if input fails due to end-of-file.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522504/istream-behavior-change-in-c-upon-failure) that is the correct behaviour specified by C++11.

So your results can be explained. When you input `42 42 42 12 13 13^Z`, it is the same as if you had written `42 42 42 12 13 13x`.  The first six numbers are read, and then when `x` is encoutered, `cin >> val` fails and sets `val` to `0`.

But when you press Enter and then `^Z`, it is as if you were reading from a file and you reached the end of the file. `cin >> val` leaves `val` unchanged and it is still holding the value that it had after the last successful `cin >> val`.

If you make the change suggested by Gautam Jha suggested then you will get `13` in both cases. This is because he effectively reads into a temporary int, and then only stores the temporary int into the real `val` if the read succeeded, thereby avoiding the behaviour where a failed read sets `val` to `0`.

This is probably the desired behaviour although you might also want to check `cnt > 0` to avoid a weird output in the case of totally empty input.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

See the difference

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int c_val = 0,val = 0,cnt = 1;
    std::cin>>c_val;
    int curr_val = 0;
    while(std::cin>>val){ // in case of no value cin will set val =0
        curr_val = val;
        if(curr_val == c_val)
            cnt++;
        else{
            std::cout<<c_val<<" occurs "<<cnt<< " times"<<std::endl;
            c_val = curr_val;
            cnt = 1;
        }
    }

    std::cout<<curr_val<<" occurs "<<cnt<<" times";
}
```

Comment: Yes I can see the difference and I could've achieved the same outcome just by replacing val by c_val in my code, but I want to know why does val behave the way it does.

Comment: As you can see in comments "cin>>val" will set val =0; when no more input available. that's why you see "0 occurs 2 times" instead of "13 occurs 2 times"