# Examples of code successfully compiled in C++11 and pre-C++11 that behave differently

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

**C++11** brought new keywords and new changes to core aspects of the language.
So could it be possible to successfully compile the same piece of code in both **C++11** and **pre-C++11**, but get different results from each binary?  By  **pre-C++11**, I'm referring to **C++98**, **C++03**, or **C++TR1**.

The reason I ask, is because I have a bunch of small programs all written in C++.  I am unaware what standard was in mind for each individual program written.  Is the behaviour of these programs guaranteed to be the same if they all compile in **C++11** as well as an earlier standard?  I would like to compile them all in **C++11**(if they can be), but avoid any subtle changes that may cause the programs to behave differently had an earlier standard been in mind.

Working examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11

Comment: Is that the reason one writes unit tests and perform regression testing?

Comment: @chris no, not breaking changes.  changes across standards that still compile but behave differently

Comment: @EdHeal agreed, but I'm interested in specifically knowing the non-breaking but differently behaving changes across C++ standards.

Comment: @TrevorHickey, There are plenty of examples there that compile, but behave differently.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: If the meaning of my code is changed, I still would consider it a breaking change. A change from "meaning X" to "meaningless" is just a particular instance of the more general notion of a change from "meaning X" to "meaning Y".

Comment: @TrevorHickey - Does testing identify when something behaves differently? How about optimization between different versions of the compiler?

Comment: The item about narrowing conversions, if correct (I don't have the standard on this machine), is pretty bad. I recently answered a question where I was "pretty sure" that it couldn't break C++03 code wholesale this away. But apparently it does...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As chris points out, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11) is a duplicate of this question.  However I did not see in the answers to that question the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    X() {std::cout << "X()\n";}
    X(const X&) {std::cout << "X(const X&)\n";}
};

int
main()
{
    std::vector<X> v(3);
}
```

In C++03 this outputs:

```
X()
X(const X&)
X(const X&)
X(const X&)
```

In C++11 this outputs:

```
X()
X()
X()
```

For almost all code, this makes no difference.  However "almost" is not "always", so this is a breaking (behavioral difference) change.  You can blame me personally for this change.  Without it:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v(3);
```

would not have compiled.  And I considered this case sufficiently motivating for the breakage.