# Manually set C++ language version for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++03

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, and want to manually set the language version to a previous version, Is this possible?

Comment: what is 4.8.1 ? GCC version?

Comment: Sorry I meant the language version that precedes C++ 11

Comment: I don't believe Visual C++ supports this (other than being able to use the C++ compiler from a previous version of Visual Studio, but not sure how far back that goes.). Also, Microsoft's support for C++ standards is generally phased across multiple versions.

Comment: BTW the C++ version preceding C++11 is C++03. C++ standards are: C++98, C++03, C++TR1 (2007), C++11.

Comment: @DracoM. You might have meant C++03? That's what I assumed in my answer. Here is the [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Standardization) of versions [Wojtek Surowka](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2382136/wojtek-surowka) mentioned. Here is [Wikipedia's summary of C++03](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B03).

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing?  C++ standards are specifically designed so that programs written against a previous standard remain valid programs in the newest standard.  If you need to compile a program that relies on compiler-specific/nonstandard behavior then you have no choice but to use exactly the compiler that it was designed to be used with, or fix the code to conform to the standard.

Comment: @bcrist C++11 is not 100% compatible with C++03 code. Even for conform C++03 code.

Comment: @bcrist Visual Studio 2012 has a lot of usability improvements over previous versions. It's nice to use the latest editor even if your code isn't compatible with the latest compiler.

Comment: @MatthiasB True, but generally, well written C++03 code is valid C++11 code.

Comment: @bcrist `int decltype = 0; int nullptr = 5` is well written C++03 code, but will result in compile errors in c++11, and [there are quite a few more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11).

Comment: @JonathanMee Agreed, but that's not really what the OP asked.  The wording of the question implies he wants to use the VC11 toolchain, but somehow magically have it parse C++98 or C++03 code.

Comment: @DracoM. Perhaps you can adjust your question per [bcrist](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1571944/bcrist)'s point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of.

Microsoft sort of decides for itself what it will use in each version. For example Visual Studio 2010 was mostly a C++03 animal but you could use some C++11 features like `auto`.

Anyway the way you'd switch to Visual Studio 2010's compiler (or some other supported version) would be in your project's property pages: "Configuration Properties" > "General" > "Platform Toolset"
Then just pick the version you want to use.

Comment: There is no such thing like C++99

Comment: This *does* mean that you need that version of Visual Studio installed and working. In other words: it is just using the newer IDE but compiling with the older version.

Comment: @crashmstr An excellent point that is noted by Microsoft here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx