# Why does std::cin modify the value of its operand even if it fails?

Tags: c++, c++11, input

I strongly believed that [`std::basic_istream::operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) is "transaction safe", i.e. if it fails, it leaves its operand unchanged. So, I was expected that for the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss("a");
    int i = 42;
    ss >> i; // extraction fails
    std::cout << i; // modifies i, WHY?!
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/464648a07e942300)

the value of `i` would stay `42`. However, starting from C++11 this doesn't seem to be the case anymore, and the operand is zeroed on failure. Quoting from [`cppreference.com`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) (emphasize mine)

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), `value` is left unmodified and `failbit` is set. (**until C++11**)
>
> If extraction fails, **zero is written to `value`** and `failbit` is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is written and `failbit` flag is set. (**since C++11**)

Can anyone explain what is the reason for this modification? I find the behaviour undesirable, to say the least. Even if I compile with `-std=c++98`, gcc5.3 and clang3.6 still behave C++11-compliant.

Comment: I got trapped by this one, too.

Comment: @5gon12eder Yeah, me too, when trying to validate some input (while trying to answer a question on SO ;)), and was pulling my hair out trying to figure out what was going on... The question I asked is a bit off, as I ask for a reason, not a programming question per se. But I hope someone close to the C++ "crystal palace" (i.e. the standardization committee) may be able to provide a reason.

Comment: Also linked to in the other question is an answer in [What breaking changes are introduced in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19523324) Also surprisingly all linked defect reports were opened in 1998 already but just took until C++11 to make it in.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Thanks for finding the duplicate question. The answer is not very clear, will try to look at some links within the comments.

Comment: `-std=c++98` doesn't change the library, only compiler rules (and even then incompletely)